# "Read" command in bash script is being skipped

Tags: bash, user-input

I'm creating a script to update my linux distribution if I need to wipe the HD or I need to install Linux on another machine. So this script basically install all the programs I usually need. At the beginning a have a "read" command that asks if I want to install all the packages automatically or not. If I choose not, for each program not found it should ask me I want it to be installed and I use this code

```
if [[ $installall == "yes" ]]; then
    echo " Installing $sciprog..."
    sudo apt-get install -y $sciprog >/dev/null
    {
        scitest=`dpkg -s $sciprog | grep Status`
    } 2>${HOME}/musthave.errorlog
    if [[ $scitest != "Status: install ok installed" ]]; then
        echo " I've encountered problems installing $sciprog that I can't resolve. "
        echo " Consider installing $sciprog manually. "
        {
            echo "=========="
            echo " $sciprog"
        } >>${HOME}/musthave.notinstalled
    else
        echo " $sciprog installed correctly!"
        {
            echo "=========="
            echo " $sciprog"
        } >>${HOME}/musthave.installed
    fi
else
    echo " Seems like $sciprog is not installed... Do you want to download it?"
    echo " Type 'y' for yes."

    read secondyn ### THIS IS THE GUILTY COMMAND ###

    if [[ $secondyn == "y" ]]; then
        echo " Installing $sciprog ..."
        sudo apt-get install -y $sciprog >/dev/null
        {
            checkinstall=`dpkg -s $sciprog | grep Status`
        } 2>>${HOME}/musthave.errorlog
        if [[ $checkinstall != "Status: install ok installed" ]]; then
            echo " I've encountered problems installing $sciprog that I can't resolve. "
            echo " Consider installing $sciprog manually. "
            {
                echo "=========="
                echo " $sciprog"
            } >>${HOME}/musthave.notinstalled
        else
            echo " $sciprog installed correctly!"
            {
                echo "=========="
                echo " $sciprog"
            } >>${HOME}/musthave.installed
        fi
    else
        echo " Skipping $sciprog ..."
        {
            echo "=========="
            echo " $sciprog"
        } >>${HOME}/musthave.notinstalled
    fi
### some more code which works as expected. All the code above is inside a 
### while...do...done loop which reads line by line the file at the end
done <${HOME}/file.list
```

But if I run the script, it skips the "read" command in the else clause and assumes it to be "n"...

I can't figure out why, there are other read function also inside `if...then...else...fi` loops and they work as expected...

Any ideas?

Comment: It's hard to tell because it looks like your indenting got mangled horribly in posting, but you seem to be missing a final `fi`.  Also, the `read` works for me.

Comment: Also, what is the shebang at the top of your script? `#!/bin/bash` or other? AND, just to be sure, you **are** running this from a command-line in a terminal session, yes? If you are crontabing it, the script will read a '' as the result and keep going. Good luck.

Comment: @jw013 well, maybe it has been cut while I copied/pasted it but the fis are correct, otherwise the script would raise an error

Comment: @shellter it's `#!/bin/bash` yes. And yes, I run the script from the command line using `./script.sh`

Comment: @Vieler : Forgot to ask, do you see the messages above the `read` but inside the `else`? (It seems like you know what you're doing, so sorry for asking what is probably too obvious a question) ; Good luck!

Comment: @shellter Don't worry, actually I'm not that good in bash scripting, it's rather new for me. Anyway, yes, the echo commands work fine and I see the strings printed on stdout.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The relevant portions of the code are still not complete but based on the comments I'm going to guess that your while loop looks like

```
while read -r ... ; do 
    # do stuff ...

    # read user input
    read -r var

done < file
```

From this the problem is immediately apparent: the inner `read` is getting its input from the same place as the outer loop, namely stdin which has been redirected from `file`, and not the user.  For a slightly more portable alternative that does not depend on kernel-level support for `/dev/tty`, just use a different file descriptor other than stdin for the while loop.

```
while read -r ... <&9; do
    # loop stuff

    # stdin still attached to the terminal untouched, 
    # so this reads from the terminal as expected
    read -r var 

done 9< file
```

Notice that this example uses fd 9 for the file, leaving fd 0 (stdin) alone.  Take a look at the BashFAQ [089](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/089) for more details.

Comment: Yes, that was the problem. Also I guess this solution is better for portability so thanks for putting me on the right track.

Answer (score 9):

Try reading from the controlling terminal device:

```
read secondyn </dev/tty
```

Answer (score 1):

```
read secondyn < /proc/${PPID}/fd/0
```

That will look to the parent's input, which should still be stdin.